# Clang Pragma Error: marked ‘override’, but does not override

Tags: c++, clang

I was trying to add a new pragma in clang and follow steps in [LLVM document](https://llvm.org/devmtg/2017-06/2-Hal-Finkel-LLVM-2017.pdf) (Start from page 30). I've add new annotation in `TokenKinds.def`,

```
ANNOTATION(pragma_begin_mark)
```

and define `Pragma Handler` in `Parser.h`

```
std::unique_ptr<PragmaHandler> BeginObfHandler;
```

Then I added new struct in `ParsePragma.cpp`. I 've also override the HandlePragma function as follow.

```
namespace{
struct PragmaBeginMarkHandler : public PragmaHandler{
    PragmaBeginMarkHandler() : PragmaHandler("begin_mark"){}
    void HandlePragma(Preprocessor &PP, PragmaIntroducerKind Introducer,
                    Token &FirstToken) override; 
};
}
void PragmaBeginMarkHandler::HandlePragma(Preprocessor &PP,
                                             PragmaIntroducerKind Introducer,
                                             Token &FirstToken){
    MyPragmaHandler(PP,FirstToken,true);
}
```

However, after every is done, I recompile clang by `make clang` and get the following error messing.

```
/home/yuweitt/llvm/llvm-project/clang/lib/Parse/ParsePragma.cpp:30:10: error: ‘void {anonymous}::PragmaBeginMarkHandler::HandlePragma(clang::Preprocessor&, clang::PragmaIntroducerKind, clang::Token&)’ marked ‘override’, but does not override
   30 |     void HandlePragma(Preprocessor &PP, PragmaIntroducerKind Introducer,
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /home/yuweitt/llvm/llvm-project/clang/include/clang/Lex/PPCallbacks.h:21,
                 from /home/yuweitt/llvm/llvm-project/clang/include/clang/Lex/Preprocessor.h:29,
                 from /home/yuweitt/llvm/llvm-project/clang/lib/Parse/ParsePragma.cpp:16:
/home/yuweitt/llvm/llvm-project/clang/include/clang/Lex/Pragma.h:74:16: warning: ‘virtual void clang::PragmaHandler::HandlePragma(clang::Preprocessor&, clang::PragmaIntroducer, clang::Token&)’ was hidden [-Woverloaded-virtual]
   74 |   virtual void HandlePragma(Preprocessor &PP, PragmaIntroducer Introducer,
      |                ^~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/yuweitt/llvm/llvm-project/clang/lib/Parse/ParsePragma.cpp:30:10: warning:   by ‘void {anonymous}::PragmaBeginMarkHandler::HandlePragma(clang::Preprocessor&, clang::PragmaIntroducerKind, clang::Token&)’ [-Woverloaded-virtual]
   30 |     void HandlePragma(Preprocessor &PP, PragmaIntroducerKind Introducer,

/home/yuweitt/llvm/llvm-project/clang/lib/Parse/ParsePragma.cpp:340:53: error: invalid new-expression of abstract class type ‘{anonymous}::PragmaBeginMarkHandler’
  340 |   BeginMarkHandler.reset(new PragmaBeginMarkHandler());
      |                                                     ^
/home/yuweitt/llvm/llvm-project/clang/lib/Parse/ParsePragma.cpp:28:8: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘{anonymous}::PragmaBeginMarkHandler’:
   28 | struct PragmaBeginMarkHandler : public PragmaHandler{
      |        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /home/yuweitt/llvm/llvm-project/clang/include/clang/Lex/PPCallbacks.h:21,
                 from /home/yuweitt/llvm/llvm-project/clang/include/clang/Lex/Preprocessor.h:29,
                 from /home/yuweitt/llvm/llvm-project/clang/lib/Parse/ParsePragma.cpp:16:
/home/yuweitt/llvm/llvm-project/clang/include/clang/Lex/Pragma.h:74:16: note:   ‘virtual void clang::PragmaHandler::HandlePragma(clang::Preprocessor&, clang::PragmaIntroducer, clang::Token&)’
   74 |   virtual void HandlePragma(Preprocessor &PP, PragmaIntroducer Introducer,
```

It seems that struct I added is considered as a anonymous struct, and hence the `marked ‘override’, but does not override` error occurs. But the struct I added is the same as other inherent pragma struct. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Judging by the error message the second parameter of your function should be of type
`clang::PragmaIntroducer`, not `clang::PragmaIntroducerKind`.

You don't use this parameter, so it should be easy to change the code accordingly.

Comment: Yes!! I didn't notice that, thanks a lot!